# Creating a Workflow Sending Form Automatically to Reviewer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Working in SP13. I am creating of a workflow that includes:
The user fills out a form and submits it to a chosen reviewer.  After submitting the form the form is submitted automatically to the reviewer.  I am not sure how the workflow should start. What action would I use to send a form to the designated reviewer? To have the form sent to the chosen reviewer, should  i create a separate email action to be sent to each reviewer on the list with an if/else statement? Sorry for the confusion, I am still learning how to create custom workflows.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First off I still use SP2010 workflows on our SP2013 site because I’m more familiar with them, but the following steps should be useable in SP2013 workflows unless something has changed that I'm not aware of.

It looks like what you’re after is an "approval workflow" these are pretty easy to set up. You'll need to install SharePoint designer (SPD) if you haven't already. Then within it create an approval workflow (there’s hundreds of tutorials online if you google "SharePoint approval workflow how to")

If your user selects a reviewer in their form, you'll need to make this selection visible to SharePoint, to do this publish your form with the AccountID field of the reviewer as a column. This would probably be then hidden in your SharePoint library so users don't see it as a column.

Once that’s done you can set up your approval workflow and use a "Workflow Lookup for User" and select that ID field as the recipient.

Hope this is enough to put you on the right path, if you get stuck anywhere feel free to leave a comment.

Edit:

Also all workflows when edited in SPD have the option to "Start workflow automaticaly when item is created" and "Start workflow automaticaly when item is changed". Using these you should be able to acheive the functionality your after.

Comment: Thank for your response. It was very helpful. Based on your advice i found this link (http://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/sharepoint-custom-approval-workflow-with-dynamic-approvers-using-sharepoint-designer/) I think this will help me build on what you mentioned. Thanks again